# Netbeans on Mac - Jar files greyed out in open dialog

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

[image]

I am trying to add a library in a jar file to a Netbeans project. However, whenever I open the folder containing the jar file, the jar file is greyed out and cannot be selected. I have checked the permissions and it should be available to read. Does anybody have any ideas what the problem might be?